# Compare Url case sensitive

Tags: .net, http

Is there any class-method to test if two urls that differ in casing are the same?

these are the same :

1. www.mysite.com
2. Www.MYsite.COm

these are NOT the same :

1. www.youtube.com/v=AAAABBBB
2. www.youtube.com/v=aaaaBBBB

EDIT
I dont think Uri class is enough

these two are the same links

1. stackoverflow.com/questions
2. stackoverflow.com/QUESTIONS

Comment: the `Uri` class breaks all that out.  Just pick the pieces you want and do your comparison.

Comment: Careful: while stackoverflow.com/questions and stackoverflow.com/QUESTIONS may direct to the same resource, this is not true in the general case. The path on the server may well be case-sensitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `www.youtube.com/v=ObgtZwwiKqg` is an incorrect URL. Correct URL contains query symbol, e.g. `www.youtube.com/watch?v=ObgtZwwiKqg`.

How about ignore path up to query and only compare the query params? If your URLs have the query `?` in them, then you can strip everything up to query. If not, you could at least strip domain with `UriPartial.Authority`.

For example:

```
Uri a = new Uri("http://www.google.com/subdirectory?v=aaBB");
Uri b = new Uri("http://www.Google.com/SUBdirectory?v=AAbb");

string aParams = a.ToString().Replace(a.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path), String.Empty);
string bParams = b.ToString().Replace(b.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path), String.Empty);
if (aParams.Equals(bParams)) // with case
{
    // they are equal
}
```

Comment: [Best practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465121(v=vs.110).aspx#recommendations_for_string_usage) recommend to use `String.Equals` for equality comparison instead of comparing the return value of `String.Compare` to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Need to use the Uri class, and check also the AbsolutePath property

```
string url1 = "http://www.youtube.com/v=AAAABBBB";
string url2 = "http://www.youtube.com/v=aaaaBBBB";

Uri u1 = new Uri(url1);
Uri u2 = new Uri(url2);

if(string.Compare(u1.Host, u2.Host, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) == 0)
{
    if(u1.AbsolutePath == u2.AbsolutePath)
        Console.WriteLine("Equals");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Not equal path");
}
else
    Console.WriteLine("Not equal host");
```